# Automatic height form/table with Sketch

Tags: text, sketch-app, tables

Is it possible to create a form or a table that is height automatic with Sketch? Like when we write text the text box expands down and expands the rest of the form or table.

I'm trying to do that with symbols, but I don't know if there's a better way.

An example of the type of form I'm trying to create:

> [image]

I want to make a form that can be filled, but the description part can have more than one line, and I want to make them expand automatically, and make the strokes go down with the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on your description, it seems like you should be using the [AutoLayout](https://github.com/AnimaApp/Auto-Layout) plugin. This is a super powerful plugin that lets you do many neat things with layouts of elements, but the specific functionality that can help you is "stacks", where you have elements on top of each other, and the plugin automatically spaces them, even if you change their height (mini demo [here](https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/auto-layout-introducing-stacks-flexbox-for-sketch-c8a11422c7b5#6680))